# Data does not display from PDO and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Sorry if the title is vague, was unsure how to word it.
Currently, I'm trying to just do a simple piece of php that runs a query and displays all the data in the database, but no data is displaying the page is just completely blank.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";

try {
  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', $username, $password);
  $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM contacts');
  $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));

  $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if ( count($result) ) { 
    foreach ($result as $query_row)
      {
       extract($query_row);


        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$fname.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$lname.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$title.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$deparment.'</td>';
        echo '<td><a href="mailto:'.$email.'">'.$email.'</a></td>';
        echo '<td>'.$cell.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$handle.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$steam.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$skype.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
      }
    }   
  } else {
    echo "No rows returned.";
  }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

I've never worked with PDO before so I've been following a guide/reading different SO questions trying to get a grasp on it.  One line that I think may be screwing up is this line:

```
$stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));
```

I don't understand what that line is doing and if an I can get an explanation that would be great.  I believe I understand the logic behind the rest of the code though.

Comment: Is `error_reporting` and `display_error` is turned on? I suspect an error has occurred, but it's being hidden; hence the blank/white page. Also it appears your select query does not have a `where` clause.

Comment: You need to tell PDO to throw exceptions and then you will see what the problem is (you have no bound variables for example): `$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', $username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));`

Comment: `$stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));` is executing the prepared statement.  The array being passed in is supposed to be used for parameter substitution, but you don't have any parameters in your query, so this makes no sense and will cause error. Just change to `$stmt->execute()`.

Comment: `var_dump($result)`. it's probably NOT an array, causing count() to fail and skipping all of your echo code.

Comment: Why I feel like an idiot..there was an extra closing } but the error was being hidden like you said.  I'll have to find where to fix that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem (it worked on my server).

*Plus*, I added the `<table>` and `</table>` tags and placed in their respective locations.

```
<?php
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";

try {

  // uncomment for testing purposes as noted by jeroen
  // $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', $username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

  $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database', $username, $password);
  $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM contacts');
  $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));

  // $stmt->execute(); // as noted by Mike Brant

}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

  $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo "<table>";

  if ( count($result) ) { 
    foreach ($result as $query_row)
      {
       extract($query_row);

    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$fname.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$lname.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$title.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$deparment.'</td>';
    echo '<td><a href="mailto:'.$email.'">'.$email.'</a></td>';
    echo '<td>'.$cell.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$handle.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$steam.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$skype.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
      }
    }   
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain? Enlighten me ;-) Downvoting without an explanation helps no one.